# Pact.io, Junit - How to test againts multiple consumers with different tags?

Tags: junit, pact

I have multiple (not only junit) consumer applications, which create pacts in pact broker.
These consumers have many different git branches - e.g.:

- `consumer1`: `release123, release007, release999`
- `consumer2`: `release69, release420, release50`

**Question**

- how to run provider tests against specific combinations of consumers and their tags?
- e.g. consumer1 release007, consumer2 release69 AND release50 ?
- is these something like `-Dpactbroker.consumers=consumer1:release007,consumer2:release69,consumer2:release50` ?

I especially need this for junit, as we mostly use java apps as providers.

**What I have found:**

- in junit, there is annotation `@PactBroker` which allows you to specify `tags` and `consumers`
- according to description, these can be set via system properties `pactbroker.tags` and `pactbroker.consumers`
- there can be specified multiple of each, separated by comma - e.g.: `-Dpactbroker.consumers=consumer1,consumer2`
- **I havent found if tags and consumers can be paired while running provider tests**

Answer (score 0):

Please try below solution might be it will help

**You can add like below on Provider Class**

API used

```
 import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.IgnoreNoPactsToVerify;
 import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.Provider;
 import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.State;
 import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.loader.PactBroker;
 import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.loader.PactBrokerAuth;
 import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.loader.PactFolder;
 import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.target.Target;
 import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.target.TestTarget;
 import au.com.dius.pact.provider.spring.SpringRestPactRunner;
 import au.com.dius.pact.provider.spring.target.SpringBootHttpTarget;
```

Provider Added on Class

```
    @IgnoreNoPactsToVerify
    @PactBroker(
    authentication = @PactBrokerAuth(password = "*******", username = "********"),
    host = "*******",
    tags = {"test", "dev", "latest"},
    port = "*****",
    failIfNoPactsFound = false,
    protocol = "http")
```

**On consumer end you can add on each test case like below**

API used

```
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.Pact;
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.PactProviderRuleMk2;
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.PactVerification;
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.dsl.PactDslWithProvider;
import au.com.dius.pact.model.RequestResponsePact;
```

Test Case Level

```
@Pact(consumer = "consumer-service-name")
```